# return nested fields using elastic4s

Tags: scala, elasticsearch, elastic4s

I have data stored with a nested location object and can't figure out how to get elastic4s to return the location as part of the result of a search.  I have data that when queried (from the REST endpoint) looks like this:

```
{
    "_index": "us_large_cities",
    "_type": "city",
    "_id": "AU7ke-xU_N_KRYZ5Iii_",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
        "city": "Oakland",
        "state": "CA",
        "location": {
            "lat": "37.8043722",
            "lon": "-122.2708026"
        }
    }
}
```

When I try querying it using elastic4s like so:

```
search in "us_large_cities"->"city" fields("location", "city", ) query {
filteredQuery filter {
  geoPolygon("location") point(37.9, -122.31) point(37.8, -122.31) point(37.8, -122.25) point(37.9, -122.25)
}
```

I get back results like this:

```
{
  "_index" : "us_large_cities",
  "_type" : "city",
  "_id" : "AU7keH9l_N_KRYZ5Iig0",
  "_score" : 1.0,
  "fields" : {
    "city" : [ "Berkeley" ]
  }
}
```

Where I would expect to see "location" but don't.  Does anyone know how I specify the fields so that I can actually get the location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try using [source filtering](https://github.com/sksamuel/elastic4s/blob/master/guide/search.md#source-filtering) instead, as shown below. Note the use of `sourceInclude` instead of `fields`.

```
search in "us_large_cities"->"city" sourceInclude("location", "city") query {
filteredQuery filter {
  geoPolygon("location") point(37.9, -122.31) point(37.8, -122.31) point(37.8, -122.25) point(37.9, -122.25)
}
```

Comment: This works! I just have to then call .getSource on the hits instead of calling .getFields etc.

Comment: @DannyHatcher FYI source and fields are different, fields show you what it looks like after tokenization and source is the original document in json.